# Como desativar data e hora passadas no calendário do jQuery UI?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

Gostaria de saber como posso criar uma função que desative as datas passadas no jQuery UI. Por exemplo, agora são 15/09/2014 07:31:25, como desativar qualquer date e hora anterior a essa hora atual?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o [minDate nas opções do datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).

Diz a documentação que pode usar três tipos no valor dessa opção:

> **Data:** Uma data especifica.
> **Numero:** O numero de dias a contar de hoje. 0 para hoje, negativos para datas passadas.
> **String:** Uma string formatada como defenido na opção dateFormat, por exemplo "+1m +7d" representa 1 mês e 7 dias da data de hoje.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/6dhuy25f/

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```